# Bash Process To Echo to Stderr WITHOUT Redirection

Tags: java, linux, bash

I'm inside another language (Java) using ProcessBuilder, but that's kind of beside the point. I need a bash process that will write to stderr that I can call using ProcessBuilder.

Example:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("echo", "a");
Process p = pb.start();
p.getErrorStream(); // I need this to return "a".
```

I've tried adding ">&2" in the constructor of `ProcessBuilder`, but it says that there's no command for `>&2`. I've tried using `echoerr`, but that's a bash function, not a real command, so it can't find it. Is there any command that I can use without forwarding that returns stderr? Awk? Perl? Anything? :D

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command using `bash` (or `sh`) to use the redirection operator:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class StdErr {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "echo a >&2");
        Process p = pb.start();
        try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()))) { // I need this to return "a".
            r.lines().forEach(System.err::println);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs: `a` (to the Java process's standard error stream)